# Ad Close Event For InterstitialAd Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, admob

i am implemeting google interstitial ads in my app ads are showing nice and good i just want to get the ad close event for this ad i searched through internet but i did not get any ad close event for this ad here is my code

my interface

```
public  interface IAdInterstitial
{
    void ShowAd();
    void LoadInterstitialAd();
}
```

my android custom renderer

```
public class AdInterstitial_Droid : IAdInterstitial
{
    InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    public AdInterstitial_Droid()
    {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Android.App.Application.Context);

        // TODO: change this id to your admob id  
        interstitialAd.AdUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        LoadAd();
    }

   public void LoadAd()
    {
        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded)
            interstitialAd.Show();

        LoadAd();
    }

    public void LoadInterstitialAd()
    {
        var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
    }
}
```

how i can get the ad close event for this ad so that i can do some stuff on ad close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own AdListener subclass that listens for the `OnAdClosed` event and than invokes your own action:

#### Example usage:

```
public AdInterstitial_Droid()
{
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(Android.App.Application.Context);
    interstitialAd.AdListener = new MyAdListener(() =>
    {
        // Ad closing, do whatever you need to do
    });

    // TODO: change this id to your admob id  
    interstitialAd.AdUnitId = "xxxxx";
    LoadAd();
}
```

#### AdListener subclass

```
public class MyAdListener : AdListener
{
    Action OnCloseAction;

    public MyAdListener(Action OnCloseAction)
    {
        this.OnCloseAction = OnCloseAction;
    }

    public override void OnAdClosed()
    {
        OnCloseAction?.Invoke();
        base.OnAdClosed();
    }
}
```

Comment: where to put this myadlistener class in pcl project or only in android project?

Comment: can i call this interstitialAd.AdListener = new MyAdListener(() =>
    {
        // Ad closing, do whatever you need to do
    }); in some other class where i want to do something on ad closing

Comment: @MastiBrozTop You are calling your original code via a dependency service, that is where you are creating a new InterstitialAd instance (in your  AdInterstitial_Droid .ctor) and when you should be assigning your AdListener subclass instance. You can always add the "OnClose" `Action` to your dependency service interface and pass it in from your NetStd2/Forms code.